# Adding certificates using policies.json from an online source

Tags: firefox, certificate

I am trying to add a certificate on the installation of firefox, and I found another similar question where an answer suggested using a policies.json file to install the certificate.

[Ubuntu18 firefox Add trust to a exsisting certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60375325/ubuntu18-firefox-add-trust-to-a-exsisting-certificate)

I am trying, however, to use a certificate that I do not have local access to, but is stored on the web. I tried to use the URL as the file location, but that does not work.

Here is my code:

```
{
    "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
        "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
        "Install" [
            "cert_name",
            "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.der"
                   ]
             }
        }
    }
```

Is there any way to install the certificate from a site?

EDIT:
I now see that I have the following message in about:policies#errors "Error parsing JSON file". So perhaps that is what is causing it not to work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the question on the mozilla support forum, and apparently this is not a supported feature.

See the forum link [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1344324).